# Lambda expression sneakily capturing `this`

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Suppose I have the following.

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    std::function<int()> f1() { return [=](){ return x; }; }
    std::function<int()> f2() { return [=](){ return this->x; }; }
    std::function<int()> f3() { return [this](){ return x; }; }
    std::function<int()> f4() { return [this](){ return this->x; }; }
    std::function<int()> f5()
    {
        int temp = x;
        return [=](){ return temp; };
    }
}
```

And now I have the following code.

```
auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
a->x = 5;
std::function<int()> f = a.f#();
a.reset();
int x = f();
```

where the `f#` is referring to any of `f1, f2, f3, f4, f5`.

These functions are exhibiting behavior in one of two sets:

1. return 5 when called (`f5`), or
2. crashed trying to dereference `nullptr` (`f1, f2, f3, f4`).

I understand that this is because some are capturing "`this`" in the member function of `A`, either implicitly or explicitly.

**What is the formal rule that's determining behavior 1 or 2?**

I spent a while dealing with a bug that was caused by something similar to `f1`, thinking it would capture `x` and never considering it would capture `this`, so I figured it would be useful to get this documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no formal rule that determines this behavior. Because this behavior is *undefined*.

Your lambdas are accessing an object that doesn't exist. You can't capture a member variable directly by value; you always capture them by `this`. Which means you're capturing them by reference. Once the object is deleted, any attempt to access that deleted object results in undefined behavior.

The exception to this is `f5`, which should return a consistent value, guaranteed. It's completely disconnected from the originating object.

Comment: Oh - I labelled the groups `f1, f2, f3, f4` and `f5` backwards! Yes, I meant it was `f5` that works correctly and the others that do not. Edited.